# Validation on a single DataGridView column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

How can I perform validation on a particular DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column in my DataGridView, so that a user is required to enter a value into it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think you are looking for datagrid view text box column validation right ? if so would you pls take a look at this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/93691/Validations-inside-DataGridView-TextboxColumn.aspx

**EDIT 1:**

you Can use this solution but it validates only numbers ,or if you want  to validate the text you can change  the code..

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell = dataGridView1[2, e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewTextBoxCell;

    if (cell != null)
    {
         if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
         {
             char[] chars = e.FormattedValue.ToString().ToCharArray();
             foreach (char c in chars)
             {
                  if (char.IsDigit(c) == false)
                  {
                           MessageBox.Show("You have to enter digits only");

                           e.Cancel = true;
                           break;
                    }
              }
          }
     }
}
```

NOTE: this code is not tested ..

Comment: @AbidAli i have edited My solution , this only validates the numerical digits only , if you want to validate the text you can change that code.....

Comment: @pratapk:: It takes degits. Ok. But dot(.) is not taken